# TypeError: Cannot read property 'PERSISTENT' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to play a video on ionic. When I launch my app I get the above error on my console which refers to this line of code

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
```

This is the code block of the js file

```
//Function for fetch video files from ionicrecorder folder from memory and set in list
    $scope.func = function(){
        //$rootScope.show('Accessing Videos.. Please wait');
        $window.requestFileSystem($window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {

          fs.root.getDirectory('ionicrecorder', {create: true}, function(dirEntry){
                  var dirReader = dirEntry.createReader();
                  dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                    if(entries.length === 0){
                      alert("No Videos available...");
                      $rootScope.hide();
                    }
                      var arr = [];
                      processEntries(entries, arr, function(arr) {
                        $scope.files = $scope.dup;
                        $rootScope.hide();
                      }); // arr is pass by refrence
                  }, onError);
                }, onError);

            //Error
                function onError(error) {
                    alert("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
                }
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

==============EDITTED=====================
Error I am currently having

```
-master>cordova plugin add github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
Fetching plugin "github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file" via plugin registry
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
Error: ENOENT, stat 
on\IonicVideoRecorder-master\github.com\apache\cordova-plugin-file'
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$window.requestFileSystem($window.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
```

Comment: You answer would be more useful, if you explain it a little bit.

Comment: I wrote something similar a few weeks ago and that works for me.

Comment: Ok, i was able to rebuild the error.
It happens when you try it with ionic serve and/or don't have the file plugin installed.

Comment: So which of the file plugin

Comment: I am now getting this error TypeError: $window.requestFileSystem is not a function

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

That is the plugin i use.

That and don't use ionic serve and it should work.

Comment: I will do it now... stay close

Comment: I am having this challenge npm err add local could not install plugin

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

or

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: That is what I am doing